Paypal new integration with API not calculating sales taxes automatically
My web site is currently using an old Paypal Integration that is working perfectly fine for adding sales taxes automatically BY PAYPAL when the client enter his BILLING address in the Paypal checkout form. That integration is using predefined taxes rates that we define in our Paypal Business profile, for example a specific tax rate for Canada/Quebec, then a different tax rate for Canada/Ontario, etc. So when I sell an item to a client for example $100, and when I send the client to Paypal with the old integration, as soon as the client specify his billing address that match with his credit card, Paypal add the correct predefined tax rate to the item amount and update price to example $115.
The new integration that Paypal is promoting to use now (with CreateOrder and ApproveOrder API) is not capable of doing this. I contacted Paypal and they said that we now need to calculate the tax amounts on our side before sending the client to Paypal, which to me does not make sense because 1. when I send the client to Paypal I am not aware of his country/province/state, and 2. Even if I would add dropdown list to my web form before sending the client to Paypal, anyone could use any location to lower tax rates or simply just avoid them. The good/secure thing about taxes automatically calculated by Paypal with the old integration is that they are using the client billing address that MUST match with their credit card, this way no one can avoid being charge the correct taxes on their purchase.
Can anyone provide any solution for that with the new integration? Paypal told me that there is a OnShippingChange method that can update/patch the CreateOrder when a client specify a shipping address, but I am selling digital services with the NO SHIPPING flag when I send the Create Order response. I would rather need a OnBILLINGAddress change methods, but it does't seems to exist.
I attached 2 screenshots to show the difference between the old and new Paypal integration behaviors.



Let me clarify this for you: the old PayPal tax and shipping calculator is more than 20 years old and was designed for simple yellow HTML buttons, back when websites were simple pages not capable of calculating shipping and tax themselves.
All of the subsequently released PayPal integrations are API-based and no tax/shipping calculation is done by PayPal. All of the PayPal integrations released since 2005 or so expect totals to be passed via API.
The only exceptions to what I just said are the integrations you may find at https://www.paypal.com/buttons . Those are all simple integrations designed for websites that are not API-capable, and may have some tax/shipping features available, although to the extent they are available they are probably rudimentary.

Anyway, as for a solution to calculating shipping and tax: PayPal is not normally willing to return a billing address so if you don't want to collect a shipping address as part of the PayPal transaction, then the best solution is probably going to be to prompt for a billing country+postal code before opening the PayPal checkout.
Since you're using the JS SDK for approval, you could have inputs for those details directly above the PayPal buttons and use the validate user input feature to require valid selection/input before the PayPal checkout will open.

I understand my current integration is very old. But why newer integration (API based or not) should equal to less options? It's not like charging accurate tax amounts to buyers was not important... Like I said, yes I could add Country/Province/State drop down list to my web forms before sending the client to Paypal, but anyone could enter invalid information to avoid taxes. I could probably also use geo localisation API, but once again, the old integration was validating the billing address MATCHING THE CREDIT CARD and this way we were 100% sure that the correct taxes were applied...

Also, API capable or not, previous integrations had item pricing variables to be passed for the items, so were also capable to send taxes amount... The only difference is that you were able to auto calculate them by Paypal which totally make sense to use.

The billing address on the card doesn't matter legally, the buyer's physical location does. Anyway, it's interesting to suggest different features but I can only tell you nothing like it exists for any API-based PayPal integration

I understand your point, but it is (in my opinion) much safer to determine which tax rate should be apply to a transaction by using the billing address for the credit card, than the buyer physical location (IP) which can be easily change using VPN... thanks for getting back to me and for confirming that an old and working solution, even if 20 years old, hasn't been added to the latest integrations :(
